# Appium Windows Driver - Ctrl is pressed after finishing

Tags: wpf, appium

I wonder if anyone experienced that - after the executable is finished (using Appium Windows driver for WPF application) - the Ctrl is pressed.
I experienced it on 2 out of 3 machines and cant find the reason why it is happening

regards,
arbus

Answer (score 0):

You can verify at the along your test if Ctrl key is pressed, but to do that you will need to standby your test and only after Ctrl be pressed your test will run till the end.
Otherway your test will run so fast you will not press Ctrl at the right moment of that `Assert` verification.